# Python regex match space-separated words that contain two or fewer o characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am new to python and trying to solve some problems (in the way to learn).

I want to match space-separated words that contain two or fewer o characters.

That is what I actually did:

```
import re

pattern = r'\b(?:[^a\s]*o){1}[^a\s]*\b'

text = "hop hoop hooop hoooop hooooop"
print(re.findall(pattern, text))
```

When I run my code it does match all the words in the string..
Any suggestion?

Comment: You could read about regex and train on a site like [regex101](https://regex101.com/). There your pattern is explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
pattern = r'(?<!\S)(?:[^\so]*o){0,2}[^o\s]*(?!\S)'
text = "hop hoop hooop hoooop hooooop"
print(re.findall(pattern, text))

# Non  regx solution:
print([x for x in text.split() if x.count("o") < 3])
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ERx5HB). Both yield `['hop', 'hoop']`.

The `(?<!\S)(?:[^\so]*o){0,2}[^o\s]*(?!\S)` regex matches

- `(?<!\S)` - a left-hand whitespace boundary
- `(?:[^\so]*o){0,2}` - zero, one or two occurrences of any zero or more chars other than whitespace and `o` char, and then an `o` char
- `[^o\s]*` - zero or more chars other than `o` and whitespace
- `(?!\S)`  - a right-hand whitespace boundary